# Is Correct to group all general settings in one table or create table for each one?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-normalization

I have a table with 9 columns sharing same data (GN_PLACE_ID,GN_AR_NAME,GN_EN_NAME)

**is good why to save them in one table or create table for each one ?**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GENERAL](
    [GN_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GN_PLACE_ID] [int] NULL,
    [GN_AR_NAME] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [GN_EN_NAME] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [GN_IS_DEVICE_TYPE] [bit] NULL,
    [GN_IS_ISSUE_TYPE] [bit] NULL,
    [GN_IS_REPAIR_TYPE] [bit] NULL,
    [GN_IS_CANCEL_REASON] [bit] NULL,
    [GN_IS_SUSPEND_REASON] [bit] NULL,
    [GN_IS_MANUFACTURER] [bit] NULL,
    [GN_IS_DEPARTMENT] [bit] NULL,
    [GN_IS_PRIORITY] [bit] NULL,
    [GN_IS_SUPPORT_SECTION] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GENERAL] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GN_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

thanks

Comment: I don't follow your question. If you mean will the RDBMS be quicker at selecting a single row, with many columns, rather than many rows (from different tables) with a single column, then the answer will very likely be "yes, it will be faster at selecting a single row."

Comment: Yes, of course it is good to put them all in a single table if each of the rows in the table refers to a single entity and the columns describe each of those entities in particular.